# Style android switch via styles.xml

Tags: javascript, android, switch-statement, react-native

I am using react native, and I cant figure out how to change thumb color of switch for "on" state. I know that there are some props for coloring but there is no ability to change color for thumb only on "on" state, like it changes in native android.
Also I cant find style key for changing switch color globally.

Answer (score 0):

In Google's dev docs there is nothing to change colors of Switchpreferences via XML.

You can try to add an onDragListener in your PreferenceActivity:

```
   mSwitchPreference.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
   // set color here
   return false;
   }
   });
```